# Exhibit five primes of the form $n^2-2$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> It has been conjectured that there are infinitely many primes in the form $n^2-2$. Exhibit five such primes.

I'm so confused what the problem is asking. Do I just need to find examples or an actual proof?

Comment: You need to find examples. “Exhibit” just means show particular examples.

Comment: Surely you aren't asked to prove an open problem; I think the question only wants you to give $5$ such numbers.

Comment: Here is one: $3^2-2=7$. Four more?

Comment: Hint: Consider numbers $n < 10$ with $n$ prime.

Comment: I guess you need to find 5! or Exhibit them
what about $n=3,5,7,9,11$

Comment: @mjb4 $n = 2,3,5,7,9$ works, but not $11^2 - 2 = 7 \cdot 17$.

Comment: damn I thought DFW mentioned 119 but yes it was 109!

Comment: Ten thousand examples in an [OEIS file](https://oeis.org/A028871/b028871.txt)

Answer (score -1):

"Exhibit" just means find, so we are looking for $5$ prime numbers that are two less than a square.

First note than an even number squared minus $2$ will always be even, except in the case of $2^2 - 2$, so let us start there and proceed checking the odd numbers.

Let's list the first few square numbers and subtract $2$ from each and see what we get

\begin{align*}
    2^2 &\to 4-2 = 2 \qquad \text{ prime}\\
    3^2 &\to 9-2 = 7 \qquad \text{ prime}\\
    5^2 &\to 25 - 2 = 23 \qquad \text{ prime}\\
    7^2 &\to 49 - 2 = 47 \qquad \text{ prime}\\
    9^2 &\to 81 - 2 = 79 \qquad \text{ prime}
\end{align*}
and we have found $5$ such primes!

Comment: Why waste your time and the time of anyone who follows the active question queue with an answer to a nine year old question that should not really have been asked?

Comment: Just to get it out of the unanswered queue.

Comment: Then we need better ways to get it out if thecqueue. Deleting requires multiple voters with the privilege to agree. Might it be possible to remove a question if its score is negative or after a certain amount of time since asking?